# How to implement Spring Security @PostFilter for different types when using OAuth

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-acl

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Security Oauth and Spring Security in my project, which is a REST server that returns `ResponseEntity<>` from it's controller methods.

Now when I add `@PostFilter` annotation to a controller method that returns `ResponseEntity<Iterable<WebUser>>` the execution subsequently fails because method `filter(Object filterTarget, Expression filterExpression, EvaluationContext ctx)` can only work with objects of type `Collection` and `Array`. It is unable to extract the collection from the ResponseEntity.

Now my answer was to extend the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` implement the filter method with extracting from ResponseEntity and using it by having `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` class that extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and overrides the `createExpressionHandler()` method.

The above would work if I wouldn't be using Spring Security OAuth because as I found out the `OAuth2MethodSecurityConfiguration` creates its own `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and my custom one then doesn't get created.

The solution was to copy the whole `OAuth2MethodSecurityConfiguration` class to my project and change one line to make it create `MyOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` that extracted the `ResponseEntity` but this solution seems kind of hacky to me.

So, finally for the question I'd like to ask if there is a better way of solving this. Maybe I went at it from a bad angle and missed a more straightforward solution.

EDIT: Going around the problem is certainly an option too, but I'm mostly looking for other (cleaner) ways of configuring Spring @PostFilter to work with ResponseEntity<> (If there are any) to better understand Spring Boot as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the data at service level

```
@Service
class TamasServiceImpl implement TamasService{
    @PostFilter
    public Iterable<TamasUser> loadAll(){
        // return you data here
    }
}
```

then in controller

```
@Autowired
TamasService service;

@Get
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<TamasUser>> loadAll(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.loadAll(),HttpStatus.FOUND)
}
```

Comment: Nice idea :) I was so set on having security annotations on controller methods that this didn't even occur to me. But in our team we agreed on having those annotations there and I'm not forcing a change on that based only on this minor issue. I'd like to find a nicer, cleaner solution for modifying @PostFilter to work with ResponseEntity<>.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a self reference.
This way Springs AOP can work its magic.
But this comes with its own drawbacks.

The code would look like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @Lazy
  @Autowired
  MyController self;

  @Autowired
  MyService myService;


  public ResponseEntity<List<WebUser>> findAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(self.findAllFilteredByTenant());
  }

  @PostFilter("filterObject.tenant.equals(principal.tenant)")
  List<WebUser> findAllFilteredByTenant() {
    return new ArrayList<>(myService.getAll());
  }
}
```

Decide for yourself, whether you like it or not.